# Dummynet installation on all components on system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ipfw, dummynet

I have a setup of 1 master node (which doubles as slave) and 2 slave nodes. I installed dummynet on the master node and configured the rules. I am wondering if I will have to do the same on the slave nodes as well(i.e install dummynet and setup exact rules).

Also do I need to setup 2 pipes to allow data movement in both directions between 2 nodes?

For ex:- is this enough?

```
sudo ipfw add pipe 3 ip from vm3 to vm1
```

or will I need another pipe from vm1 to vm3?

2) Can the setting between vm2 and vm3 be setup on vm1?

3) When I setup the rules, for example configure the link between vm1 and vm3 to be of 100 MBits/sec, I don't see it reflected in the real system when I run iperf, I get something like 3.7 Kbits/sec.